# Why does Cygwin refuse to execute nbtstat?

Tags: windows, cygwin

I have cygwin installed on Windows 7. Cygwin will run every other `C:\Windows\System32\` command I've tried e.g. `ipconfig` **except** `nbtstat`.

`nbtstat` works as expected in `cmd.exe`. I have even tried running the Cygwin shell as administrator and it still won't execute `nbtstat`. It won't even show up in `ls -l`.

Why does cygwin refuse to execute `nbtstat`?

Comment: Are you sure its running stuff from the system folder? I believe it has its own version of each tool.

Comment: Yes I am sure because I type in the full path to the executable in the shell.

Comment: I strongly suggest anyone to **try** this first themselves and see if they run into the same problem.

Comment: Nah, Cygwin is deprecated in my opinion. If you are feeling need to use some Linux shell commands on your Windows I strongly recommend MSYS. You can use them directly from cmd.exe, no need to enter an ackward Bash simulator.

Comment: It runs fine in my Win7 box under both cmd and cygwin bash. I can also `ls` it: `$ ls -l /cygdrive/c/Windows/System32/nbtstat.exe` returns `-rwxrwx---+ 2 ???????? ???????? 15360 Jul 14  2009 /cygdrive/c/Windows/System32/nbtstat.exe`

Comment: @Havenard is there an Ubuntu equivalent to nbtstat that will list the device **names**, not just MACs?

Comment: @paxdiablo this is very odd. I also noticed in "Properties" panel, nbstat had original filename nbtinfo

Comment: Afaik `nbtstat` is related to Windows Networks and NetBIOS. If theres any equivalent to Linux it probably belongs to the Samba package.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My psychic debugging powers tell me you're running the 32-bit version of Cygwin on a 64-bit version of Windows.

Try running `/cygdrive/c/Windows/sysnative/nbtstat.exe` instead.

Comment: would this have been better asked on serverfault?

Comment: Superuser, I should think.  I voted to migrate rather than close.  If you'd specified that this was in the context of writing a bash script or some such it would probably have been considered on-topic, it's a bit of a grey area.